# How can I do bandwidth management using quotas on a Debian Linux based router?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, quota

I use a Debian Linux based PC as a router. Now, I want to implement bandwidth management using quotas. By that I mean when a user has reached their quota limit, their bandwidth will be reduced.
I've searched for it online, but I haven't found any information on how to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of designing your own router, and doing so many customisation, you should better go for PfSense, which is an industry class firewall with Almost everything you need.
It is opensource and free.

Comment: I don't hear about PfSense before.. Maybe, I should learn about it. Ok, thx for your suggestion. I will google how to implement my plan with PfSense.

Comment: Yea, if you want a more heavy weight solution (and with 100 users it sounds like you do) i'd say go with this option.

Comment: @Sirex pfsense is free solution and it has ability to handle more than 10-4000 users/server

Comment: I know. I just meant heavyweight compared to cobbling something together in bash. pfsense is the way to go for the OP, i agree.

Answer (score 1):

I've never needed to do this, so i'm guessing here, but...

You may be able to do this with tc. I'd imagine its not the best solution though. Essentially you'd classify the traffic into groups then check how much ends up in each bucket, altering the bandwidth of the group when the limit is reached.

Another method might involve iptables, making a table for each user and then counting how much goes through each table.

Comment: hmm.. I have more than 100 users.. I can't do that.. That is not efficient.. hemm.. yeah I think that I can't do this with simple way..